# Different types of Apps Developed in Sybase Unwired Platform

Tags: html, sup, web-container

I want know the different types of apps developed in Sybase Unwired platform.please send me any materials or web links related to SUP .

Thanks in Advance........

Answer (score 0):

Sybase Unwired Platform supports two main modes of application development: native application development
and hybrid Web development. Native application development makes sense when user interface expectations or application performance depend on device-specific capabilities.

Hybrid Web development is best for cross-platform apps that run on multiple devices. It provides a lower cost of development for extending workflow processes such as approvals or requests.

You can find everything in related to this in the sybase info center.

Regards
Midhun